# How can I log to a specific file path with log4j2 in a library?

Tags: java, log4j2, slf4j, class-library

I have a Java Library (SDK) that will be consumed as a JAR in other applications. I'm using log4j2 and SLF4J to log right now, but when my library is consumed by the other application (also using log4j2.xml) the logs are not created. I need to be able to log to a specific directory and path with a specific file name (rolling appender).

I've tried searching for information on this, and it seems like using SLF4J as a facade is the way to go, but I can't find anyway to provide my own file path, format and configuration.

Is it bad practice to do this? I do this in C#, TypeScript and every other language, I only seem to have this problem with Java.

As I understand it, the SLF4J provides a facade for the developer who uses my library to use their own logging framework. If I rely on the developer who is implementing my library to include a logging library, how can I guarantee my logs are being generated? I need to be able to troubleshoot issues from the field, if a bug is reported, I need to be able to review the logs to see what went wrong.

Am I using the wrong logging for this use case? Is there some way I can specify a different configuration file for log4j2 that isn't overridden by the consuming application's configuration?

To clarify, I have a "libary" which is really just an API with methods to obscure and simplify making WebSocket calls. This API will be consumable by other applications. I need to log to a specific file path to ensure that if there are issues, I can trace them through the log files to find out the root of the issue. I can't rely on the consumer of the API to implement their own logging implementation and configure it to a specific path. I have a log4j2.xml, but it seems like this is overridden if the consuming library is also using its own log4j2.xml.

[image: Here's a diagram I hope helps]

In the image, the blue and orange JAR have different log4j2.xml files. I have no control over the orange, only the blue.

Please help.

Comment: A library is not supposed to provide configuration files to a target application. The application needs to provide it's own. So basically you can make a log4j.properties in the application and use it to control your output.

Comment: @Barracuda So, you're saying Java doesn't support the use case for specific logging in a closed-source library/API that obscures methods to be consumed by another Java application?

Comment: It's not really about the language not supporting it. More like the ecosystem is not build to favor this kind of solution. You can probably still access the library's logging config file through reading it's Jar at runtime, but it's more complicated  than it is worth.

Comment: @ThomasYamakaitis it is not clear what you are asking. Java has nothing to do with this. You are talking about the SLF4J facade and the log4j2 implementation. SLF4J doesn't has any configuration because it is a facade. You need to configure lgo4j2 if you haven't, which is not clear in your question. 
As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Barracuda XML configuration is the most common these days for log4j2. Suggesting using the properties file could cause confusion because most examples are for log4j2.xml

Comment: @aled sorry, if my question is unclear, I just tried to clarify. I'm just confused and frustrated because it's hard to find information. I have log4j2 configured, but it seems that when the JAR is consumed, the log4j2.xml is overridden. I'm wondering if there's a way to prevent or circumvent this (i.e. a custom configuration file).

Comment: Can you draw a diagram about the dependencies and where the log4j2 configurations are and so on?

Comment: @Easterwood I added one, hopefully it helps explain.

Comment: In deed it did. I faced a similarly situation some times ago and as far as I know I repacked the `Library Jar` and removed the `log4j2.xml` (automated via maven...). But I would expect (like you) that the blue and the orange jar both use the same `log4j2.xml`.

Comment: Do both (blue and orange jar) use SLF4J to get the `Logger` instance? Maybe you could provide some code examples of how the jars use the `Logger` instance.

Comment: @Easterwood sorry to be clear, the log4j2.xml is different for each. I have no control over the orange JAR's log4j2.xml in production. I only have control over the blue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256735/discussion-between-easterwood-and-thomas-yamakaitis).

Comment: Typically, logging configuration in the Java ecosystem is left to the _application_, not each individual _library_. Even which logging _implementation_ to use is typically left to the application. Your own library is using a facade (SLF4J) instead of using a logging framework directly. And that brings up a potential issue: You're trying to add custom configuration only for your library expecting Log4j as the implementation, but what if your client(s) decides to use Logback, JUL, or some other framework instead? What if they change frameworks in the future?

Comment: That said, maybe something from [this Stack Overflow search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Blog4j%5D+or+%5Blog4j2%5D+multiple+configurations) or [this Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=log4j+multiple+distinct+configurations) can help. The idea from Easterwood of creating your own private `LoggerContext` used only within your library—and loading the configuration from a uniquely-named config file/resource—seems like it would work. But note I've never done something like that, so I cannot _guarantee_ it will work for you.

Comment: @Slaw thank you for the helpful comment. I've seen something about LoggerContext, but I'm struggling to find information on how to setup my own LoggerContext. I recognize that I seem to have a unique situation. It's just strange to me that there seems to be no simple way of handling logging for this scenario. I will try to figure this out and if I come up with something, I will be sure to answer my own question.

Answer (score 0):

After a few helpful comments, I believe the solution is to use a ConfigurationFactory to specify a separate "private" LoggerContext and a custom log4j2 configuration file as a ConfigurationSource. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be a lot of information out there about doing this.

Here's what worked for me, in the constructor for my logger, I first check if the Configuration file exists, if it doesn't I call my static createConfiguration method (below). If the configuration file exists I create a ConfigurationFactory and point it to my specified configuration file, then create a custom Configuration using the Configuration file as the ConfigurationSource and a new "private" LoggerContext:

```java
protected CustomLogger() throws IOException {
   // Check if the Configuration file exists
   if (!configFile.isFile()) {
        createConfiguration();
   }

   // Get instance of configuration factory on Startup
   ConfigurationFactory factory = XmlConfigurationFactory.getInstance();

   // Create a "Private" LoggerContext instance
   LoggerContext context = new LoggerContext("PrivateLoggerContext");

   // Locate the source of your configuration
   ConfigurationSource configurationSource = new ConfigurationSource(new 
   FileInputStream(new File(configFilePath)));

   // Get a reference from configuration
   Configuration configuration = factory.getConfiguration(context, configurationSource);

   // Start logging system
   context.start(configuration);

   // Get a reference for logger
   logger = context.getLogger("com.packagename");

   logger.info("TEST");
}
```

And in my logger class, I have a static "createConfiguration" method that programmatically generates the configuration file and outputs it to my desired file path (in this case, "C:/ProgramData/PackageName", however I suggest allowing your library users to specify a path and just provide a default):

```java
public static void createConfiguration() throws IOException {
    // Create the configuration directory if it doesn't exist
    new File("C:/ProgramData/PackageName").mkdirs();

    // Create a ConfigurationBuilder to build out the configuration
    ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    AppenderComponentBuilder consoleAppender = builder.newAppender("console", "Console");
    LayoutComponentBuilder patternLayout = builder.newLayout("PatternLayout").addAttribute("pattern", "%d{MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSSS} [%t] %-5level %logger - %msg%n");
    consoleAppender.add(patternLayout);

    builder.add(consoleAppender);

    LoggerComponentBuilder logger = builder.newLogger("com.packagename", Level.DEBUG);
    logger.addAttribute("additivity", false);
    logger.add(builder.newAppenderRef("console"));

    builder.add(logger);

    builder.writeXmlConfiguration(new FileOutputStream(configFile));
}
```

Finally, in the constructor for my library I create my Logger just like usual:

```java
public Library() {
    Logger logger = new CustomLogger();
}
```

I hope this answer helps someone in the future who may run into this, and if anyone has any recommendations or comments about the code here, please feel free to comment. I will edit if needed.

References for this answer:

- [Log4j2 Example Tutorial - Configuration, Levels, Appenders](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/log4j2-example-tutorial-configuration-levels-appenders)
- [Programmatic Configuration with Log4j 2](https://www.baeldung.com/log4j2-programmatic-config)
- [Apache - log4j Programmatic Configuration](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Configurator)